# How to configure a subdomain that uses almost the same files as the top level domain?

Tags: centos, web-server

I have mydomain.com at public_html/ and m.mydomain.com at public_html/m/ running on CentOS. m.mydomain.com is just a direct copy of all of the files from mydomain.com except for one configuration file that tells the site to switch to mobile. I know this setup is horrendously difficult to maintain but what is the best way to set this up so I don't have to maintain two separate sites that use essentially the same files except one? Is there a way to use "shortcuts" (pardon the Windows parlance) for m.mydomain.com to the actual files in mydomain.com so that a change in one automatically affects the other?

**Notes** The configuration file is a php file that just has the flag $go_to_mobile = TRUE.

Comment: Could you change location of the configuration file? For example, move it to separate folder - "config" or something like that

Comment: I guess my question, put in another way, would be how can I get a user that goes to m.mydomain.com, hit that configuration file at public_html/m, then have the user continue browsing on m.mydomain.com instead of getting redirected to the TLD? I just figured that the config file HAS to be in the m.mydomain.com directory.

Comment: What kind of config file is it? A .htaccess?

Comment: It's a php file that just has a flag like $go_to_mobile = TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not programmer, but I think it could be something like

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] == "site1.example.net")
        include_once "config.php";
    else
        include_once "m.config.php";
```

Comment: The problem though is referring back to the files in the main TLD directory. Right now, I have to copy files from the TLD to public_html/m/ directory just to have two copies of the same site run on two different domains. Setting aside the configuration file for a moment, let's just say I want m.mydomain.com to run exactly like mydomain.com. How can I go about doing that without redirecting to the TLD? I know I'm probably not explaining this well enough.

Comment: I think you could add m.mydomain.com as alias in config file of mydomain.com

Comment: Like in the .htaccess?

Comment: No, I mean ServerAlias directive in apache.